# Counting the pairs in a list such that their first index is less than the second but the first element is greater than the second

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

I have the list `[5,2,10,9,7]`.
I want to count all the pairs that satisfy the condition  `( i<j and list[i]>list[j] )`
For example, the index of 5 is less than the index of 2 but 5 is greater than 2 so increase the counter by 1 and the same for (10,9) and (10,7)and (9,7) so the value of the counter will be 4

I have solved the problem but with complexity O(n^2), but I want to find a solution with the lowest time complexity.

This is the code that runs on O(n^2)

```
 def ques(lista):
     b=0
     for i in range (len(lista)):
        for j in range (1,len(lista)):
            if i<j and lista[i]> lista[j] : 
                b+=1
     return b
```

Comment: It can be done in a single iteration ;)

Comment: @NirAlfasi I have tried to do it with one for loop but it ignores the last element

Comment: My bad, I missed the fact that (10,7) should also be counted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mergesort should be able to do this in O(nlogn).
During the merge process, when we have to merge the left and the right array, we compare the first elements of both the arrays, if first element of the right array is less than the current first array of the left array, pop it, add it to a new temp array. Also increment the counter by the length of the left array (since all the elements in the left array are greater but have a smaller index).

```
def mergeSort(a):
    if len(a) >= 2:
        mid = len(a)//2
        left, right = mergeSort(a[:mid]), mergeSort(a[mid:])
        temp = []
        i, j = 0, 0
        for _ in range(len(a)):
            if i < len(left) and j < len(right):
                if  right[j] < left[i]:
                    temp.append(right[j])
                    # here we are counting are our pairs
                    counter[0] += len(left)-i
                    j += 1
                else:
                    temp.append(left[i])
                    i += 1
            elif i < len(left):
                temp.append(left[i])
                i += 1
            else:
                temp.append(right[j])
                j += 1
        return temp
    else:
        return a


counter = [0]
arr = [5, 2, 10, 9, 7]
mergeSort(arr)
print(counter[0])
```

Comment: No, actually this question is not about how to sort an array.

Comment: You don't have to sort it, just when comparing the two lists in merge, increment counter if you find an element in the right list with value less than the first element in the left list.

Comment: @aksh02 I have tried to do this but it doesn't work, I would be so thankful if you show me the code

Comment: @aksh02 + how I will  compare the elements of the right list with each other?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done in less than O(n^2):

The fact that each element should be compared with all the elements that come after it means that for the first element we'll need:
n-1 comparisons, for the following element we'll need n-2 comparisons an so on.

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 2 + 1 => order of n^2
```